# In Views, how do I get a link directly to an image file (not the node containing the image file)?

Tags: views, media

I have a view that displays nodes in *fields* format.

I have a *Global text* field in which I want to display the URL of images contained in nodes; however, I can't find how to get the URL of the images.

What I've tried:

- I added the Image field and chose "Content" as the option for "Link to."  This is the link I want, but this prints out the image too (I don't need the image) and I can't use this field as a replacement pattern.
- I added a link to the content itself, but then this gives me a link to a node, not the image.

In Views, how do I get a link directly to an image file (not the node containing the image file)?

Comment: What you want to try to achieve? real senarioo ?

Comment: I need to output the image link because I want to add it as the query string to a Google reverse image search lookup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option that doesn't require installing a new module:

- Create a Relationship to the image for which you want to create a link
- Add a field File:Path
- Exclude from display
- Rewrite Results - output this field as a link
- Add the replacement pattern to your global text

Comment: In my case, I also needed to check *Display download path instead of file storage URI* under the File:Path options in Views, because Google requires a download URL; it won't accept a Drupal path.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [Image URL Formatter](https://drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) module.

This module provide a image formatter as Image URL.

Select That formater in views .

[image]